# Flutter google_pay implementation

Tags: flutter, in-app-billing, google-pay, flutter-in-app-purchase

So have searched all through the whole internet to see if I can get any code to help with google pay integration for flutter to replace my existing Java android code but the closet was https://pub.dev/packages/google_pay which loads Google play UI but payment not successful as it shows an error that Unrecognised app.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Pay flutter package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/google_pay#-installing-tab-).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_pay/google_pay.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';
  String _googlePayToken = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      platformVersion = await GooglePay.platformVersion;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    await GooglePay.initializeGooglePay("pk_test_H5CJvRiPfCrRS44bZJLu46fM00UjQ0vtRN");

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Running on: $_platformVersion\n'),
              Text('Google pay token: $_googlePayToken\n'),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Google Pay Button"),
                onPressed: onButtonPressed,
              )
          ]    
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onButtonPressed() async{
    setState((){_googlePayToken = "Fetching";});
    try {
      await GooglePay.openGooglePaySetup(
          price: "5.0",
          onGooglePaySuccess: onSuccess,
          onGooglePayFailure: onFailure,
          onGooglePayCanceled: onCancelled);
      setState((){_googlePayToken = "Done Fetching";});
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      setState((){_googlePayToken = "Failed Fetching";});
    }

  }

  void onSuccess(String token){ 
    setState((){_googlePayToken = token;});
  }

  void onFailure(){ 
    setState((){_googlePayToken = "Failure";});
  }

  void onCancelled(){ 
    setState((){_googlePayToken = "Cancelled";});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @zavora. As you can see in my question I used the same link you sent to me earlier and but I got an error in saying " Unrecognised app " and I don't know where I got it wrong. Do I need to change this "pk_test_H5CJvRiPfCrRS44bZJLu46fM00UjQ0vtRN" in await GooglePay.initializeGooglePay("pk_test_H5CJvRiPfCrRS44bZJLu46fM00UjQ0vtRN"); and if yes where do I get token and does it have to start with pk_test?

Comment: @yodeveloper and Zavora, are you finally able to have this working? I am in the same boat now - looking for resources to integrate Google Pay in a Flutter app. My use case is not in-app payments but payments for ecommerce. I would really appreciate if you were able to share anything you have figured out on this topic by now..